# How have I saved Gitlab username and password in Visual Studio Code, Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, passwords, gitlab

This is a strange question, but I cannot find how I did this:

I have three computers, all of them with visual studio code and an account in gitlab. In two of them, my operation has been

```
git clone ___.git
cd folder
git init
git remote add origin ___.git
```

And then, every time I push,... I have to enter my id and pass.

**But** in my first computer, I did something that I don't need to enter the id and pass anymore, it just pushes without hassle.

Then, I thought I must have done something like this

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

But when I look for `.gitconfig`, which I find in the `/Users` folder, there I only have my `user.name` (which is not the one of gitlab), the email  (this one is the gitlab email) but **no password entry**. And I cannot find any other `.gitconfig` files anywhere. For sure I didn't set up any SSH key.

So here the question, what did I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to use the [GCMfW: Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows):

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

Then try again: that should cache your username / password, provided you are using an HTTPS (https://...) URL, not an SSH one.

Comment: But I didn't use this on my first computer. How can I know whether I have the id and pass stored somewhere?

Comment: It is normally set by default. Try it on your second computer, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried but definitively it sounds as if this had to be the case, as I read it here https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/git_credential_manager_with_windows_subsystem_for_linux.html